# What is difference between SGD classifier and SGD regressor in python?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

What is difference between SGD classifier and SGD regressor in python sklearn?  Also can we set batch size for faster performance in them?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's in the name. SGD Classifier is a model that is optimized (trained) using SGD (taking the gradient of the loss of each sample at a time and the model is updated along the way) in classification problems. It can represent a variety of classification models (SVM, logistic regression...) which is defined with the `loss` parameter. By default, it represents linear SVM. SGD Regressor is a model that is optimized (trained) using SGD  for regression tasks. It's basically a linear model that is updated along the way with a decaying learning rate.

Answer (score 1):

SGD {Stochastic Gradient Descent} is an optimization method, which is used by machine learning algorithms or models to optimize the loss function.

In the scikit-learn library, these model `SGDClassifier` and `SGDRegressor`, which might confuse you to think that SGD is a classifier and regressor.

But that's not the case.

`SGDClassifier` - it is a [classifier](https://blog.datarobot.com/classification-with-scikit-learn) optimized by SGD
`SGDRegressor` - it is a [regressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) optimized by SGD.

**Stochastic gradient descent**{SGD} does not support batch, it takes single training example at a time unlike {batch} **Gradient descent**.

Example using sklearn partial fit

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
import random
clf2 = SGDClassifier(loss='log') # shuffle=True is useless here
shuffledRange = range(len(X))
n_iter = 5
for n in range(n_iter):
    random.shuffle(shuffledRange)
    shuffledX = [X[i] for i in shuffledRange]
    shuffledY = [Y[i] for i in shuffledRange]
    for batch in batches(range(len(shuffledX)), 10000):
        clf2.partial_fit(shuffledX[batch[0]:batch[-1]+1], shuffledY[batch[0]:batch[-1]+1], classes=numpy.unique(Y))
```

Comment: Thanks it clears my doubt :) but is there any module in Sklearn to implement Minibatch gradient descent? Since SGD is time consuming

Comment: That SGD does not support batches is not generally true, although it indeed holds for the scikit-learn implementation; in practice and for most of the frameworks, SGD implicitly means *minibatch* SGD...

Comment: if you have a large data set, that can not fit in the memory, then you should use the [partial_fit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.partial_fit), there is a concept in sk-learn.
i have updated my answer with the example code.

Answer (score 0):

Classifier predicts to which class belongs some data.

```
this picture is a cat (not a dog)
```

Regressor predicts usually probability to which class it belongs

```
this picture with 99% of probability is a cat
```